# How can I show my web component only in allowed websites

Tags: vue.js, web-component

I have created a web component using `vuejs`. That component calls to an `api` in my own server and shows a list of users.

This is my web component.

```
<script src="http://maywebsite.dev/web-components.js"></script>
<vue-app title="My web component"></vue-app>
```

This the way of showing this web component in other's websites.
[image]

Assume allowed websites domains are
`websitedomain1.com, websitedomain2.com, websitedomain3.com, websitedomain4.com`

What I need to do is..

1. My web component should be available only for allowed websites. If
   any other website(not allowed) copy  my js
   file(`http://maywebsite.dev/web-components.js`) and web component
   tag(`<vue-app title="My web component"></vue-app>`) of their
   website, my web component should display a error message like "You are
   not allowed to see this!".
2. The `api` for getting user list can only be called by allowed
   websites.

Please help me to get this done!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can test the value of `location.host` (and when people copy it, they can remove the test with very little effort).
2. Client-side code can't access data from your API by *default*. The Same Origin Policy prevents it. You have to use CORS to grant permission to the websites which you want to access it. So just *don't* grant permission to all and sundry.

Comment: For 1. You can increase the amount of effort required with https://blog.jscrambler.com/javascript-obfuscation-the-definitive-guide/ And don't test ``location.host`` once. Do it N times with different code, to create N hurdles

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless:

1. You also own the website you want your Javascript to run on
2. Create a browser extension that will only load your script on a specific website.

You **can't** control **where** your JS file will be ran unless you create a browser extension that will load your JS file for a specific website.